# Two periods in CSS url() pointer?

Tags: html, css, fonts, frontend

I'm looking at one of apple.com's stylesheets, and I saw this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Apple Legacy Icons';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 100;
    src: local(""), url("../assets/legacy/appleicons_text.woff") format("woff"), url("../assets/legacy/appleicons_text.ttf") format("truetype")
}
```

What I specifically don't understand are the 2 periods in the url() pointer.

```
url("../assets/legacy/appleicons_text.woff")
```

I've tried going back 2 directories, which doesn't work. I have also tried going back to the root(domain name), but both 404ed. Apple.com checks referers(and 404s if they don't match) for certain css files, so I wanted to ask this here before trying to "brute force" the actual location.

edit: if it does mean parent of the current directory, how far can I go back? Just one? an unlimited amount?

Comment: `../` means *"up one directory"*

Answer (score 3):

The `../` is a file path that gets its source from a directory back. See https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp

Answer (score 1):

In your example, the dots represent a traverse up the directory path.

So, the appleicons font is located in the legacy folder, which is located in the assets folder, which is located one directory up, or in the parent directory, from the current location where you're referencing that font (most likely the stylesheet, in this case).

You can go up as many directories as you'd like by using `../../` etc

You can learn more [here](https://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/).

Hope this helps!